# How can I use monitors plugged into my graphics card and motherboard?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, multiple-monitors

I've decided to try out Ubuntu on my desktop, but I've ran into a problem. When I first booted into it, it only detected my small monitor plugged into my motherboard. I thought of this as a non-issue, as I know Ubuntu doesn't use nonfree drivers by default. So after install, and upgrade, I selected non-free drivers for my graphics card and rebooted. Expectedly, My two monitors plugged into my graphics card are now working and fully functional. However, my monitor plugged into my motherboard is now disabled. I went to display settings, and it does not appear as a device. What can I do to use all of my monitors?

Comment: What graphics card?

Comment: ATI AMD Radeon R9 200 Series